# Create temporary table in procedure, MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need create a simple procedure, but after create a temporary table, mysql wants put 'end' after semicolon.

```
 CREATE procedure zad2()

    begin
    drop temporary table if exists temp;
    create temporary table temp as (select table_name, column_name 
      from information_schema.columns  where table_schema = 'lista3' and table_name not like 'lista');

    declare i int default 0;
    end$$
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Stored procedure have a block where you will put all code/logic .. and that block is `BEGIN` and `END` , if you have an opening block which is `BEGIN` , you need to close it with `END`, that's why MySql wants you to put `END` after semi colon.

Below link can help with the syntax:

[CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://CREATE%20PROCEDURE%20and%20CREATE%20FUNCTION%20Syntax)

Answer (score 0):

I think that what is missing is to declare the DELIMITER $$ at the start of the statement:

```
DELIMITER $$ /*To tell MySQL that your delimiter is now '$$'    */
CREATE procedure zad2()

        begin
        drop temporary table if exists temp;
        create temporary table temp as (select table_name, column_name 
          from information_schema.columns  where table_schema = 'lista3' and table_name not like 'lista');

        declare i int default 0;
        end$$
DELIMITER ; /*To tell your MySQL that you delimiter is back ';'     */
```